# Closing current form and open another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to know how the best way to close current C# form and open another one

```
DetailForm df = new DetailForm();
df.Show();
this.Hide();
this.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
DetailForm df = new DetailForm();

df.Show();

this.Close();
```

But be careful, if you close the main form the application will be closed.

**EDITED**

To run this if the first form is the main form you need do more. Try something like this:

Change your Program.cs file to this:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static bool OpenDetailFormOnClose { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        OpenDetailFormOnClose = false;

        Application.Run(new MainForm());

        if (OpenDetailFormOnClose)
        {
            Application.Run(new DetailForm());
        }
    }
}
```

And in the main form, close it with this:

```
private void Foo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Program.OpenDetailFormOnClose = true;

    this.Close();
}
```

If you set `OpenDetailFormOnClose` with true after the close of the main form, the DetailForm will be call.